# I cannot use amsmath package

Tags: amsmath

I try to compile my latex but it doesn't work. It shows the following error

> Command `\iint` already defined. `...d{\iint}{\DOTSI\protect\MultiIntegral{2}}`

The command that I'm using is as follows:

```
\documentclass{aip-cp}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{graphicx, amsfonts, amssymb, longtable}
\let\openbox\relax
\usepackage{amsthm, amsthm}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Somebody please help me.

Comment: `aip-cp` is not a standard class. You might want to update your question with information where we can get that class. BTW: you can probably just use `\let\iint\relax` before loading `amsmath`

Comment: @daleif I reproduced the error using [this version](https://github.com/gammapy/gammaskynet-gamma2016/blob/master/proceeding/aip-cp.cls) of the class.

Comment: The conflict seems to be between the class and the `amsmath` package as observed by the OP

Comment: The class loads txfonts.

Comment: @BambOo thanks, as Ulrike mentions this is because of its use of `txfonts`, just do a standard `article` doc loading `txfonts` before `amsmath` and you'll get the issue.

Comment: See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/321123/2388 for a possible work around (but better would be if the class wouldn't clash with amsmath).

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by others this comes from the fact that the class loads `txfonts` which defines some symbols that `amsmath` also defines.

Here is an even shorter MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

You can use the normal `\let...\relax` trick to remove these symbols. Turns out there are four:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\let\iint\relax
\let\iiint\relax
\let\iiiint\relax
\let\idotsint\relax
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

Comment: This document https://usermanual.wiki/Pdf/guide.451200889.pdf (apparently written by "AIP Tex support") says `txfonts` (and `hyperref`) are "optional packages", but it doesn't say how to deselect the option!

Comment: @alephzero if the class in question is the same as BambOo referred to, then you cannot. BTW: might be an idea to refer to the PDF on their own homepage instead of some website that collects random manuals (that might be out of date).

Comment: Well, that 's what a Google search for "aip-cp" found for me, and it looked likeuseful information. I don't intend to go on a treasure hunt through the AIP site to try to find out more, though.