# How can I get a line break in a theorem headline using the ieeeconf class?

Tags: theorems, amsthm, ieeeconf

*This is a follow-up question to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26042/how-can-i-get-a-line-break-in-a-theorem-headline), as suggested by Ioannis Filippides.*

The question is about the fact that a long theorem title may be longer than the column width, and it is not continued on the next line automatically. In the referenced question, it is suggested to load a package such as `amsthm`. (If this generates an error message, it can be solved as explained in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43835/conflict-between-amsthm-and-some-other-package).)

The problem is that this approach changes the lay-out (theorem title bold instead of normal, theorem text italic instead of normal) when used with the `IEEEconf` class. Is there an other way to solve the problem of the long title while maintaining the original lay-out of the `IEEEconf` class?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{ieeeconf}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
Hello, see my nice theorem below.
\begin{theorem}[A title that is too long so it stretches outside the column]
\lipsum[1]
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

Result of the MWE:

[image]

Adding `\usepackage{amsthm}` to the MWE, I obtain the error message

`! LaTeX Error: Command \proof already defined.`

and I obtain following result where the title is split over 2 lines but the lay-out is changed:

[image]

---

For reference, here's how IEEEconf (re)defines the theorem commands.

```
%% ENVIRONMENTS
% "box" symbols at end of proofs
\def\QEDclosed{\mbox{\rule[0pt]{1.3ex}{1.3ex}}} % for a filled box
% V1.6 some journals use an open box instead that will just fit around a closed one
\def\QEDopen{{\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.2pt}\fbox{\rule[0pt]{0pt}{1.3ex}\rule[0pt]{1.3ex}{0pt}}}}
\def\QED{\QEDclosed} % default to closed

\def\proof{\noindent\hspace{2em}{\itshape Proof: }}
\def\endproof{\hspace*{\fill}~\QED\par\endtrivlist\unskip}
%\itemindent is set to \z@ by list, so define new temporary variable
\newdimen\@IEEEtmpitemindent
\def\@begintheorem#1#2{\@IEEEtmpitemindent\itemindent\topsep 0pt\rmfamily\trivlist%
    \item[\hskip \labelsep{\indent\itshape #1\ #2:}]\itemindent\@IEEEtmpitemindent}
\def\@opargbegintheorem#1#2#3{\@IEEEtmpitemindent\itemindent\topsep 0pt\rmfamily \trivlist%
% V1.6 IEEE is back to using () around theorem names which are also in italics
% Thanks to Christian Peel for reporting this.
    \item[\hskip\labelsep{\indent\itshape #1\ #2\ (#3):}]\itemindent\@IEEEtmpitemindent}
\def\@endtheorem{\endtrivlist\unskip}

% V1.6
% display command for the section the theorem is in - so that \thesection
% is not used as this will be in Roman numerals when we want arabic.
% LaTeX2e uses \def\@thmcounter#1{\noexpand\arabic{#1}} for the theorem number
% (second part) display and \def\@thmcountersep{.} as a separator.
\def\@IEEEthmcounterin#1{\arabic{#1}}
% redefine the #1#2[#3] form of newtheorem to use a hook to \@IEEEthmcounterin
\def\@xnthm#1#2[#3]{%
  \expandafter\@ifdefinable\csname #1\endcsname
    {\@definecounter{#1}\@newctr{#1}[#3]%
     \expandafter\xdef\csname the#1\endcsname{%
     \noexpand\@IEEEthmcounterin{#3}\@thmcountersep\@thmcounter{#1}}%
     \global\@namedef{#1}{\@thm{#1}{#2}}%
     \global\@namedef{end#1}{\@endtheorem}}}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with `ieeeconf`, and don't know whether it's even compatible with `amsthm`.  However, `amsthm` does support three different theorem styles, of which the styles `definition` and `remark` set the content in ordinary type, and it's also possible to define new theorem styles in which the heading font is changed.  See the user documentation: `texdoc amsthdoc'.

Comment: I edited the question to include the portion of `ieeeconf.cls` that concerns theorems. Instead of loading amsthm you can consider modifying the definition of `\@opargbegintheorem` yourself. Note that currently the theorem header and headline are set as the _item label_ in a `trivlist`. So the solution could be as simple as moving the `(#3)` out from under the `\item[...]` and adjusting the spacing and font family accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You can adopt the `proof` environment from `amsthm` (with slight modifications) and define a theorem style that emulates the (horrible) one in `ieeeconf`.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{ieeeconf}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\let\proof\relax\let\endproof\relax
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{ieeeconf}
  {0pt}   % ABOVESPACE
  {0pt}   % BELOWSPACE
  {\normalfont}  % BODYFONT
  {\parindent}       % INDENT (empty value is the same as 0pt)
  {\itshape} % HEADFONT
  {:}         % HEADPUNCT
  { } % HEADSPACE
  {\thmname{#1} \thmnumber{#2}\thmnote{ (#3)}} % CUSTOM-HEAD-SPEC
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  \normalfont \topsep\z@
  \trivlist
  \item[\hskip2em
        \itshape
    #1\@addpunct{:}]\ignorespaces
}{%
  \popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\rule[0pt]{1.3ex}{1.3ex}}
\theoremstyle{ieeeconf}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

Hello, see my nice theorem below.

\begin{theorem}[A title]% that is too long so it stretches outside the column]
\lipsum[1][1-3]
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
\lipsum[2][1-4]
\end{proof}

\lipsum[3][1-3]

\end{document}
```

### Output with the fixes

[image]

### Original configuration with `ieeeconf` (just a shorter title)

[image]

Comment: The italic parentheses and following colon look pretty poor.  In theorems all punctuation and fences should really be upright.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Unfortunately that’s how IEEE wants it